# From SimpleXML to variable

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I'm reading an XML with SimpleXML.
A node is made in this mode:

```
$docType    = $doc->DocumentType;
```

If i do

```
print_r($docType);
```

I'm getting:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => B )
```

And this is right. Now, i need to "simply" put the "B" into a variable, to obtain this goal:

```
$daneadoc['B'] = 'Scontrino / Vendita al banco';
$daneadoc['I'] = 'Fattura';
```

(I have an array for several value for "daneadoc").

Obviously, if I put

```
echo $daneadoc[$docType];
```

It's     Illegal offset type

But if i write

```
 $documento = $docType[0];
 echo $daneadoc[$documento];
```

My server says same (illegal type). Same if I write

```
 echo $daneadoc[$docType[0]];
```

My question is... How i can convert obkect in a single variable to put in the array $daneadoc?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but try:

```
$docTypeString = (string) $docType;
$daneadoc[$docTypeString] = 'Scontrino / Vendita al banco';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the [`getName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php) method? You want to retrieve the tag name?

Use it like this : `$docType->getName()`

Comment: Ehm sorry. Solved myself. Simply cast (string) before accessing on node... Thank you btw!  $docType  = (string)$doc->DocumentType[0];